# Sql server - stored procedure - concatenated results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In order to build a statistical report, i need to execute this kind of request, for each 5000 agencies, and each 5 state, so 25 000 requests :

```
select count(*) from transaction where state == 1 and where id_agency==1;
select avg(duration) from transaction where state == 1 and where id_agency==1;
```

How to build a stored procedure which gathers all the results of these requests, into one list key-value  ?

```
CountAgency1CountState1 = 123;
CountAgency2CountState5 = 645;
CountAgency8AverageState7 = 987;
```

Data Table structure : 2 tables :

Table Transaction : `id_transac, duration, state, idAgency`

Table Agency : `idAgency, adress, city`

Comment: define your table structure in question, and sample output

Comment: Why not do `SELECT ID_Agency, State, Count(*) [ID_Count], AVG(Duration) [Avg_Duration] FROM Transaction group by  ID_Agency, State` EDIT turned into answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you need is to group by ID and State

```
SELECT ID_Agency
     ,State
     ,Count(*) [ID_Count]
     ,AVG(Duration) [Avg_Duration]
FROM Transaction 
group by ID_Agency
,State
```

This will give you one row per  ID and State with the 2 values you need.

Answer (score 1):

actually by assuming your data we can proceed by using AVG() and GROUP BY to get count basing on ID .it's example if you provide exact data we can get some more accurate output

```
   CREATE table #T(ID INT,Value INT)
    INSERT INTO #T (ID,Value)values (1,10),(1,20),(1,30),(2,10),(2,20),(2,30)
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE Getaverage
    (@i_id INT)
    AS 
    BEGIN 
    select DISTINCT COUNT(ID) ,AVG(value),SUM(VALUE) from #T t
    WHERE (t.id = @i_id OR @i_id IS NULL)
    GROUP BY ID
    END
```

Comment: Ok; now i need to execute this query 5 times, one for each state. Is it possible to execute 2 queries and gather the results ?

Comment: @Erixx Why do you want to do it one value at a time?

Comment: @Erixx in the procedure what ever the state you can pass that ID and get the result set otherwise if you want all pass 0 condition

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it all in the one query?

```
SELECT 'CountAgency' + 
           CAST(idAgency as varchar) + 
           'CountState' + 
           CAST(state  as varchar) As Name
       ,CountAgency
       ,AvgDuration
FROM (
    SELECT idAgency
          ,state
          ,COUNT(*) As CountAgency
         ,AVG(T.Duration) As AvgDuration
FROM [Transaction] 
GROUP BY idAgency, state 
) InnerQuery
```